# JavaScript image printing showing blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, printing

i want print image when i click image or button .. but its not printing any image its showing blank . but if i tried with text  then its working fine....

```
function CallPrint(){
    var imageControl = $('#print_item').attr('src');
    console.log(imageControl);
    var WinPrint = window.open('','','letf=0,top=0,width=1,height=1,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
    WinPrint.document.write('<img src="' + imageControl + '">');
    WinPrint.document.close();
    WinPrint.focus();
    WinPrint.print();
    WinPrint.close();
}
```

here is my html

```
<img id="print_item" src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/auth/logo-left.png" alt="" onclick="CallPrint()">
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/k6nrbz2x/

Comment: my image link was incorrect maybe...

Comment: The image does show up at the main page though, right? And the typo (`letf`) shouldn't matter either. Maybe try delaying the `print()` slightly? Using `setTimeout()`? And does my fiddle work for you?